# Pass original http_referer to other pages

Tags: php, navigation, breadcrumbs, http-referer

I have a business profile set up with a separate gallery page. The header for these pages is a php include.

I am trying to set up a breadcrumb trail for this profile so am using http_referer to track which listings page I came from.

```
if ($title == 'Business Profile'){
session_start();
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
?>
```

The problem I have is passing the http_referer as a variable from the business profile to the gallery page. How would I do this so that I can link back to the listings page from both the business profile and the gallery? If I use http_referer on the gallery page it will only take me back to the profile I came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cookies? For example on your landing page;

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    $expiryTime = time()+(60*60*24); // Set to expire after 1 day
    setcookie('HTTP_REFERER',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$expiryTime,'/');
}
```

And then on all other pages you can detect if there is a cookie already set;

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    $referer = $_COOKIE['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, thank you Stu. I will give it a go now.

Answer (score 0):

1) I you should check if referer address is not from my server.

2) If not, you can save this to session or cookie.

3) Finally you can use it as you wish;

```
<?php
session_start();
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])===FALSE){
    $_SESSION['refererPage']= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    // or set cookie by Stu
}
?>
```

Use eg.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['refererPage']))
    echo '<a href="'.$_SESSION['refererPage'].'">Back</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am trying to use http_referer to create an internal breadcrumb from my listings pages. There are 4 types of listings based on different search methods, so the server should always be my server. Ideally it would be if the server 'is' my server as I wouldn't want the breadcrumb to take me back to another site eg. google Thank you though your answer is helpful.